# How do I switch between Kwin Window tabs?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde4, titlebar, tabs

How do you switch tabs when you attach a window as the tab of another? I wasn't able to find the corresponding KWin shortcuts to modify. I have realized that scrolling over the titlebar works, but is there a key binding I could use? A custom shortcut, probably? What is the command I would have to execute to switch between tabs?

[image]

Comment: What kind of tabs?  Browser tabs?

Comment: When you attach a window to another as a tab by right clicking on the title bar as select "Attach as tab"

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of a window with multiple tabs please?

Comment: Can you do that with all windows?  (I haven't used KDE in awhile, and haven't ever heard of this feature).  You might try <alt>+<tab> or <ctrl>+<tab>

Comment: Do not use "Xyz abc efg" as a title format. It's very poor and likely to get downvoted or ignored.

Comment: @Seth <alt>+<tab> works, but treats them as separate windows, rather than tabs. Same holds for closing the tabs - they're treated as separate windows.

Comment: Did you try <CTRL><TAB>?

Comment: Yes, first thing.

Comment: Also, I think @RolandiXor is right in his answer. There isn't a single shortcut that manages these tabs. I guess they're just implemented as separate windows, but simply grouped together.

Comment: @asymptotically yep that's what it is. Compiz has a similar feature though it doesn't display the tabs in the same way.

Comment: @RolandiXor Thanks for your help! I just had a look at Compiz's feature, I prefer KWin's :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, all you have to do is use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

I checked and the only possible way to achieve this would be to write a [Kwin script](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/KWin/Scripting).

Comment: Alt + Tab switches between windows ... (though it also displays the tabs, I want to only switch between tabs like how you would on a browser). Nevertheless, this is at least a level of ease

Answer (score 5):

To switch only between tabs you can configure your own shortcut.

This can be done in the following way:

1. Go to Application Launcher → Settings → System Settings → Shortcut and Gestures → Global Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Select KWin from the 'KDE component:' combo box
3. The interested Action is 'Walk Through Windows Tabs'

This tool is smart enough to warn you if you are overriding some other keybind when the latter is defined in it. But be careful, it will not warn you if you are overriding some external application keybind.

Valid for KDE 4.12.3